# Logistic regression with latent variable problem

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm having problem solving this question:
[image]

Any help would be really valuable.

Comment: Add self study tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand{\b}{\boldsymbol{\beta}'\x}$**Hints:**
Note that $\Phi$ (standard normal CDF) is the CDF of $\varepsilon$.

For part (a), try using [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236249/how-to-proof-that-phi1-1-phi-1-for-standard-normal-distribution) that that $\Phi(-u)=1-\Phi(u)$ and $P(-\varepsilon \le u) = P(\varepsilon \ge - u)$.

For (b), note that by definition of $Y^*$, $P(Y=1\mid \x) = P(-\varepsilon < \b)$. Use the result of (a) to arrive at the answer.

Comment: I still have problem understanding how to reach ( ≤ ) in part a, can you clarify? In the part b, why is ( ≤ ′)=Φ(′)

Comment: $\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand{\b}{\boldsymbol{\beta}'\x}$For a), use $P(\varepsilon \ge -u)=1- P(\varepsilon \le u)$. For b), it is because $P(\varepsilon \le a)=\Phi(a)$ for all $a$; let $a =\b$. (I have been thinking of $\x$ as a constant, but if it is a random variable, we would write $P(Y=1\mid \x)=P(-\varepsilon < \b \mid \x)$, and since we are conditioning on $\x$, it is effectively treated as a constant still. So $P(\varepsilon < \b\mid \x)=\Phi(\b)$.)

Answer (score 0):

In part (a) you need to show the symmetry property of the normal distribution. One way would be:

for $u\geq0$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\epsilon\leq u) &= \int_{-\infty}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2)dx\\
 &= \int_{0}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2)dx\\
&= \int_{-u}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}(-x)^2)dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}(-x)^2)dx\\
&= \int_{-u}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2)dx = \mathbb{P}(\epsilon \geq -u) = \mathbb{P}(-\epsilon \leq u).
\end{align}

for $u < 0$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\epsilon\leq u) &= \int_{-\infty}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2)dx = \int_{-u}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}(-x)^2)dx\\
&= \mathbb{P}(\epsilon \geq -u) = \mathbb{P}(-\epsilon \leq u). 
\end{align}

concluding for $u \in \mathbb{R},\mathbb{P}(\epsilon\leq u) = \mathbb{P}(-\epsilon \leq u)$

Part (b):
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y=1|x) &= \mathbb{P}(Y^{*}>0|x) = \mathbb{P}(-\epsilon <\bf{\beta}'x|x) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(\epsilon < \bf{\beta}'x|x) = \mathbb{P}(\epsilon \leq \bf{\beta}'x|x).
\end{align}

since $\epsilon$ is a continuous random variable $\mathbb{P}(\epsilon = \bf{\beta'x}|\bf{x}) = 0 $. Sorry, this is a regular 0 (not a vector of zeros).